# Addition of sparse matrix using structure in c(triplet form)

Tags: c, data-structures, structure, sparse-matrix

I am currently doing a problem of addition of sparse matrices. I am making sparse matrix by using triplet form. The triplet form is made by using structure in c.

```
struct sparse
{
    int row;
    int col;
    int val;
};
```

but while doing this sparse matrix problem I encountered a problem that my code only displays the correct sparse matrix when i am giving the indices of nonzero values in increasing order (eg. (0 1 3),(1 2 5),(2 2 7) etc)otherwise it is displaying incorrect matrix.for example if am giving input like (0 1 3),(2 2 7),(1 2 5) etc then it is displaying wrong matrix. How to solve this problem so that in any order of indices it will give correct output?

I have added my input and resulting output. I have done this for two sparse matrix.

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
struct sparse
{
    int row,col,val;
};
void readmat(sparse sp[])
{
    printf("enter total number number of rows ,column of matrix and total
    of nonzero values in this\n");             
    scanf("%d %d %d",&sp[0].row,&sp[0].col,&sp[0].val);
    printf("now start entering the values by specifying index 
    position\n");
    for(int i=1;i<=sp[0].val;i++)
        scanf("%d %d %d",&sp[i].row,&sp[i].col,&sp[i].val);
}
void displaymat(sparse sp[])
{
    int k=1;
    for(int i=0;i<sp[0].row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<sp[0].col;j++)
        {
             if(k<=sp[0].val&&i==sp[k].row&&j==sp[k].col)
             {
                 printf("%d\t",sp[k].val);
                 k++;
             }
             else
                 printf("0\t");
         }
         printf("\n");
    }

}
int main()
{
    struct sparse sp1[10],sp2[10],sp3[10];
    printf("for first matrix\n");
    readmat(sp1);
    printf("for second matrix\n");
    readmat(sp2);
    displaymat(sp1);
    printf("\n\n");
    displaymat(sp2);
    printf("\n\n");
    displaymat(sp3);
    return 0;
 }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the original answer:

The reason out of order values are not getting printed is because when the value in triplet form points to an element further down the for loops go past all the other values that could have been printed. For example in your example the 3rd element is at row=1, col=3 however the 2nd element is at row=2,col=2. This will lead to the outer for-loop advancing down to 2nd row. At that point in time the loops will not go back and print 1st row.

One way will be to sort based on the row and col and then print the values.

Comment: but when we pass array to function it is the address which is passed so basically there is no difference. and also it has  nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: That's right. Looking at your code again I see an issue with the logic whic leads to all lower indices not getting printed once a higher index is encountered in the sequence.

Comment: yeah i too thinking of sorting them after user entered value and its respective index.